# img.width/height inside constructor returns zero

Tags: javascript

I have...

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'img.png';

function Class(img){
   this.img = img;
   console.log(this.img.width); //0
}

var instance = new Class(img);
```

The console log from the code above returns 0 regardless of the image size.

If I put the console log in the update function and have it generate every frame, it does return the right value

```
Element.prototype.update = function(){
   console.log(this.img.width); //581
}
```

But I don't want it to return the width every frame. I just want it once during construction. Any idea why img.width/height is always returning 0 inside the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the loading of an image resource is always asynchronous. You need to wait for its `onload` event:

```js
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png';

function Class(img){
   this.img = img;
   img.onload = e => {
     console.log(this.img.width);
   };
}

var instance = new Class(img);
```